# Can Trello actions also fire a request to my own API?

Tags: trello

My company has a project management system already, but they really like the way Trello feels. I know I can use the API to access the Trello board data, but can I also fire a request from Trello to update my own data on my server?

This way, each user could use what they're most comfortable with and all the data is in tact in both places.

Comment: I suggest considering a browser extension to drive this process. Trello itself won't initiate any communicate, you'll have to have the user do it or something "watch over" Trello. If this is an extension you could do both. Otherwise, a server process could monitor Trello via its API.. either or this sounds like a substantial dev project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trello has a planned plug-in API which will make it easier to perform these sorts of outside integrations. Sounds like what you're asking for is [WebHooks](http://www.webhooks.org/).

Trello [now has them](https://trello.com/docs/gettingstarted/webhooks.html)!

Comment: Any update on this?  Maybe webhooks are there but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Web hooks in Trello are shipping soon.

Comment: Hooray! Web hooks are here! https://trello.com/docs/gettingstarted/webhooks.html

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to do this is to use Zapier to [POST data to a webhook on your site whenever a new card is created](https://zapier.com/z/6cs/zapbook/trello/webhook/). There are probably a lot of different combinations you could come up with but the end result is you can take any data Trello makes avaialble and push it to a url on your site to capture the data.

*Just a small disclaimer: I work at Zapier. Even if I didn't I'd still find this approach useful. :)*

Comment: I would not suggest Zapier. Looking for a solution to the same problem I came across them earlier. The limitations of the number of number of pushes you can do with them per month is so restraining that its not feasible IMO (compared to the number of times you would move, add, delete Trello cards in a typo scrum environment)